# ImportError: No module named psutil

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have successfully installed `psutil` using:

```
 pip install psutil
```

It works in interactive mode and in the Python IDE, but it shows [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlLg7.png) when I run my script through the command prompt.

Comment: Please share your code and the error msg you're seeing.

Comment: How did you install `psutil`?  Also, please post text-based things as text, not as images.

Answer (score 0):

may be your virtual enviornment has not been activated 
or you installed it globally but virtual env is active.